# nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: ssh, mac-osx

I can use this command on my Mac before

> ssh `cat /my/login/host`

but I got the problem of *nodename nor servname provided, or not known* now....

If i use

> cat /my/login/host

I will get

> aloha@8.8.8.8

I also try this :

> hello=`cat /my/login/host`
>
> echo $hello     # show aloha@8.8.8.8

but ...

> ssh $hello      # nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why would you SSH into a google DNS loadbalancer?

Comment: Ha~ Just for demo ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all ~

I find the solution !

At first , I use this command

> cat -v  /my/login/host
>
> ##show aloha@8.8.8.8^M

so .... this is my problem ~

the solution as below :

> cat /my/login/host | tr -d '\015' >  /my/login/host_tmp
>
> ssh `cat /my/login/host_tmp`